# How to make a long beep in c++?

Tags: c++, macos

I'm making a program in c++ that reads Morse Code and prints it to the terminal, and gives the user the option to hear it. I know that, in order to make a "beep," you can use:

```
cout<<'\a';
```

However, since Morse Code contains with longer and shorter beeps, I would like to know how to make longer beeps than what would be produced by this command.

I'm using a Mac.

Comment: How about `long beep;` or even `long long beep;`?

Comment: @FredOverflow, How about... oh wait, `long long long is too long for GCC`.

Comment: I have no objection to humor, but you should flag it as such so people won't think you are being helpful.

Comment: Curses provides basic bells and beeps IIRC

Comment: You might want to use a serious audio library, such as OpenAL, depending on how much functionality you need. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL

Comment: The "dup" does not apply to Mac at all. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

If you write multiple bells.  i.e. `cout << "\a\a\a\a"` it will come out as a longer beep.

However you also need a way to write the `"silence"` between the beeps, and the bell sound may be different from one environment to another, so this is not really a good approach.

There is no standard library support for controlling sound on the computer, but if you look for platform-specific functionality, you are likely to find it, and ultimately this will give much better results.

Comment: A Mac will play the system alert sound for each beep, so they won't in general combine to a long tone. Macs don't have motherboard piezo buzzers like some machines do.

Comment: Hence my comment that "the bell sound may be different..."